# Windows 8 activated, can't add additional features

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

I do not see the logic in this:
[image]

Windows 8 is activated (legitimately) and yet, I can't add additional features. Why is this happening? I have reset my computer after activation, and to be honest, I don't know what to do now...

Comment: which edition do you use? Do you use a Retail or VL key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try updating the Windows Product Key:

```
Press: Windows key + R
```

Type in: **slui 3** and hit **Enter**

Enter your Windows 8 key.

Now reboot your PC.

Activate it again:

```
Press: Windows key + R
```

Type in: **slui 4** and press **Enter**

Reboot your computer again.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try re-activating your copy of Windows 8.

To do this, go to left bottom corner of your screen and **right click** to get a menu. Select **Command Prompt (Admin)**

Now, At command prompt, type in "slmgr.vbs -ipk "

```
slmgr.vbs -ipk 00000-00000-00000-00000-00000
```

Replace 0000s with your product key and press Enter.

You will get a prompt saying that the key has been installed. Next type `slmgr.vbs /ato`

You can also check detailed licensing info by typing in `slmgr.vbs /dlv`.

Hope this helps!